# Question about this proof that show $l^p$ is a complete space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

The proof comes from "Introductory functional analysis" by Erwin Kreyszig", page 35.

Let $l^p$ be the set of all sequences $\{x_n\}$ with elements in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p$ is convergent, and the metric $d_p(x, y) = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} |x_i - y_i|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}$

The proof that I'm reading for the completeness of the $l^p$ space (i.e. that every Cauchy sequence converges in $l^p$ goes as follows:

Let $\{x_n\}$ be any Cauchy sequence in the space $l^p$ where $x_m = (\xi_1^{(m)}, \xi_2^{(m)}, \dotsm)$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that for all $m, n > N$,

$$d(x_m, x_n) = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}|\xi_i^{(m)} - \xi_i^{(n)}|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p} < \epsilon $$ (3).

It follows that for every $i = 1, 2, \dotsm$, we have $|\xi_i^{(m)} - \xi^{(n)}| < \epsilon$. For a fixed $i,$ we see that $(\xi_i^{(1)}, \xi_i^{(2)}, \dotsm)$ is a Cauchy sequence of numbers, which converges in $\mathbb{R}$ since it is a complete space. So, say $\xi_i^{(m)} \to \xi_{i}$ as $m \to \infty$. Using these limits, define $x = (\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, \dotsm)$, and show that $x \in l^p$ and $x_m \to x$.

From (3), we have that for all $m, n > N$, $$\sum_{i = 1}^k |\xi_i^{(m)} - \xi_i^{(n)}|^p < \epsilon^p$$.

Letting $n \to \infty$, we obtain for $m > N$ that

$$\sum_{i = 1}^k |\xi_{i}^{(m)} - \xi_i|^p \leq \epsilon^p$$.

---

Now here's the part that confuses me:

We may now let $k \to \infty$, then for $m > N$,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} | \xi_i^{(m)} - \xi_i|^p \leq \epsilon^p$$.

How can we assume this? By doing this aren't we assuming that the limit on the left itself exists, so don't we need to prove that first? How do we prove this? Through the boundedness inequality? But again, how do we get that inequality? How do we even know we can take $k \to \infty$ and get that inequality?

Thanks, and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The sum $S$ of a series of non-negative numbers is the limit of the increasing sequence $(S_k)$ of partial sums. It always "exists" but may be $+\infty$. If $\forall k\quad S_k\le M$, then $S\le M.$